# How does Nginx restart after being killed by log-rotate?

Tags: linux, nginx, logrotate

In `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` I find:

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 nginx adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        [ -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] && kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
    endscript
}
```

It's the `postrotate` command I'm curious about.

I take this to mean that once the log has been successfully rotated, it kills the *nginx* process.

I know when restarting *nginx* the new log will be created.

What I can't work out is, how is the process automatically restarted, and is there any interruption to serving webpages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`logrotate` running as a daily cron job will rename log files in `/var/log/nginx/*.log`.
After that, nginx cannot output error log or access log to original log files. (For more details, refer to @mata's comment under this answer.)

To solve this problem, `USR1` signal should be sent to nginx to reopen log files.
That's why `postrotate` sends `USR1` to nginx master, this signal is not to kill nginx.

For more details to control nginx with signals, see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html).

Comment: It's not that it can't write to the original file anymore, in fact it would continue to do so as long as it still has an open file handle, it doesn't matter that the file has been renamed, that's why it needs to be told to close the old and open a new log file using the USR1 signal.

Comment: @mata, yes, your description is more detailed:)

Comment: Ah. Reading the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) indicates the command should be `kill -s USR1 ...`. Why is the `-s` skipped?

Comment: @J.Doe, see [this comment](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/kill.c#L419) in kill.c

Comment: @J.Doe I'm not sure what version of `kill` that man page refers to, but traditionally `kill` implementations also support the `-signal_name` or `-signal_nr` form, e.g. [util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html), [procps-ng](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1@@procps-ng.html), [coreutils](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1@@coreutils.html). The spec is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html)